# I have to append text in my d3.js code but it's not displaying text

Tags: d3.js

```
  script type="text/javascript">

  d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(data){

  var svgcontainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                      .attr("width",500)
                      .attr("height",500)

        svgcontainer.selectAll("rect")      
                     .data(data)    
                     .enter()
                     .append("rect")
                     .attr("width"  ,function (d)   { return d.age * 10;})
                      .attr("height" ,45)
                      .attr("y",function(d,i) { return i*50; })
                      .attr("fill","blue")

       svgcontainer.selectAll("text")   
                      .data(data)   
                      .enter()  
                      .append("text")
                      .attr("fill","white")
                      //.attr("y",function(d,i) { return i*50 ; })                        
                      .text( function (d) { return d.name; })

  })
```

I have to append text in my d3.js code but it's not displaying text.I am new to d3.js so please any one help me. Here is my code-

Comment: Could u plz share a working copy JSFIddle?

Comment: mydata.csv contains
"name","age"
"abi",20
"anu",22
"hari",25

Answer (score -1):

From the first observation i will get to know the issue related with the text element position in svg. In [SVG Coordinate](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html) positions are very important to achieve the graphical representation. In above code snippet x and y positions are missing. sample code below:-

```
 svgcontainer.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
  .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

[Example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7341714)